# Training im2txt fails with "ImportError: No module named inception_v3"

Tags: tensorflow

I'm attempting to get im2txt running and completed all of the steps leading to the "Initial Training" step but am having trouble with im2txt finding inception_v3.

Attached is the console output and error.

Is there something missing from the documentation or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/im2txt#initial-training

```
myMachine:~/tensorflow_models/models$ cd im2txt/
myMachine:~/tensorflow_models/models/im2txt$ bazel build -c opt im2txt/...
INFO: Found 17 targets...
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.256s, Critical Path: 0.01s

myMachine:~/tensorflow_models/models/im2txt$ bazel-bin/im2txt/train   --input_file_pattern="${MSCOCO_DIR}/train-?????-of-00256"   --inception_checkpoint_file="${INCEPTION_CHECKPOINT}"   --train_dir="${MODEL_DIR}/train"   --train_inception=false   --number_of_steps=100
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/home/user123/tensorflow_models/models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 25, in <module>
    from im2txt import show_and_tell_model
  File "/data/home/user123/tensorflow_models/models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/show_and_tell_model.py", line 29, in <module>
    from im2txt.ops import image_embedding
  File "/data/home/user123/tensorflow_models/models/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/ops/image_embedding.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.slim.python.slim.nets.inception_v3 import inception_v3_base
    ImportError: No module named inception_v3
    myMachine:~/tensorflow_models/models/im2txt$ ls -l ${INCEPTION_CHECKPOINT}
-rw-r----- 1 user123 user123 108816380 Aug 28 20:21 /home/user123/tensorflow_models/models/im2txt/data/inception_v3.ckpt
myMachine:~/tensorflow_models/models/im2txt$
```

Comment: Are you sure your tensorflow installation is up to date? May be update your [installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv-installation) and try again?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I reinstalled tensorflow but am getting the same error.